# Not able to scrape specific information off BSE website using bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the previous close and open stock price from [this](https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/bharat-gears-ltd/bharatgear/505688/) website. Here's an image as a reference to where the information to scrape is located.

[image: stock info table]

It looks like the particular table is a child of a `div` tag with `class="col-lg-13"`, but bs4 just returns `None` on all attempts to find it.

I've tried the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = "https://bseindia.com/stock-share-price/bharat-gears-ltd/bharatgear/505688/"
resp = requests.get(link).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, "lxml")

box = soup.find('div', class_="col-lg-13")
table = box.find('table')
print(table)

>>> None
```

I've also tried:

```
container = soup.find('div', attr={'ng-init': "fnStockTrading()"})
tables = container.find_all('table')
print(tables)

>>> []
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the same url (the API) the page is using for the data. This can be found in the network tab

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/getScripHeaderData/w?Debtflag=&scripcode=505688&seriesid=').json()
prev_close = r['Header']['PrevClose']
prev_open = r['Header']['Open']
print(prev_close, prev_open)
```